# On date change listener

Tags: java, android, listener

My task is to trigger a method to refresh or reset my application every time the date change (every 12am). I tried to search the web for an answer but I can't find anything. Is there any method/or listeners in android that I can use? or any approach? 
Any suggestion guys?

Comment: http://javatyro.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-date-picker-example.html - may be this can help you.You can use onDateSet of DatePickerListener

Comment: @JigarPandya OP is not asking for the DatePickerListener... He wants a notice when the date in System changes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can listen to date / time changes on Android. For this, register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for the following intent filters explicitly in your Activity:

```
android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_TICK
```

This Intent is sent every minute. You **can not** receive this through components declared in your manifest, but only by explicitly registering for it with [Context.registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29).

Your Receiver (inner) class:

```
private final MyDateChangeReceiver mDateReceiver = new MyDateChangeReceiver();

public class MyDateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        // compare current time and decide if it's 12 AM
        Log.d("MyDateChangeReceiver", "Time changed");

    }
}
```

Register it in your onResume method:

```
registerReceiver(mDateReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

and do not forget to un-register it in your onPause method:

```
unregisterReceiver(mDateReceiver);
```

Comment: I'll try this one. I'll let you know.

Comment: what is mLockscreenSentReceiver?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change mLockscreenSentReceiver to mDateReceiver  after copying it from my project. Answer updated :)

Comment: whats the difference if I use Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED?thanks

Comment: ACTION_DATE_CHANGED (as well as Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) are triggered only when the time or date gets changed manually by the user and are not automatically triggered by the system. Did this work for you?

Comment: You can find information about all the available intent filters here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to Check System Time in Background at Every Definite Time Interval & if Your desired time (12:00 am) matches the system time then do Something what you have to do.For this Task you have to use Either Async Task Or Alarm Manager.If i am not wrong then this would be the Solution to your Question hope this help you.

Comment: Running a background service for continuously checking and comparing the time is not a good idea. A BroadcastReceiver is a better idea. Please see my answer below :)