# Is there an option to get notification on the date change in android?

Tags: android, date, notifications

I want to know if any inbuilt notification mechanism is there in android when the date changes. The need is, I need to do an operation on next daay.

Example, i check for an update on reboot. then next check i need to do either on next reboot or on the next day. suppose today is January 1, i need to check for the update on January 2. so is there any way to get the notification when the date of the system changes?

Comment: I don't think that there is a **data change broad cast receiver** in android. May be you can use an `AlarmManager` for your requirement

Comment: yes this method iam aware. Thanks for the confirmation. :)

Comment: android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED is broadcast event you can use that

Comment: hi @santhosh , is this only for if the date is changed by the user manually? or will this come when the date is automatically changed everyday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On date change listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674716/on-date-change-listener)