# trigger a receiver if system date change automatically in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am a newbie for android. I have registered receiver in manifest using `android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED` and it is working fine when a user changes the date manually. BUT my requirement is receiver has to be called automatically everyday the system date change say at 12:00 am. The user should not change the date.

Thanks in advance.

my code - manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationOne"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_one"
        android:parentActivityName=".FirstActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".FirstActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastreceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".SecondBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Broadcast Receiver class

```
public class SecondBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Context mContext;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    Toast.makeText(context,"inside second",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MyBroadcastreceiver.firstConnect = true;
    MyBroadcastreceiver.hasInternet = isInternetAvailable();
    if(MyBroadcastreceiver.hasInternet) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        MyBroadcastreceiver.firstConnect = false;
    }
}

public boolean isInternetAvailable() {

    Toast.makeText(mContext,"inside isInternetAvailable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

}

one service- which has notification

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
private int notificationIdOne = 111;
private int numMessagesOne = 0;
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        displayNotificationOne();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

i have another receiver which will be called when internet is connected/disconnected.

Comment: Can you please post your code...

Comment: @naveen, can you please check i have posted my code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On date change listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674716/on-date-change-listener)